# Does Emacs 23.2 support DDE, OLE, COM or DCOM?

Tags: eclipse, emacs, ole, com+, dcom

Does Emacs 23.2 support DDE, OLE, COM or DCOM?

In other words, under Windows, can it integrate seamlessly with Eclipse as an in-place editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that.  Eclipse has Emacs key bindings built in though, you can change them in preferences - they work quite well.

Comment: Thanks. Key bindings is only a fraction of what Emacs offers but your answer definitely clears out the issue.

Comment: The Emacs+ plugin may be of interest: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/emacs

Comment: Thank you Jesper. This plugin looks promising and it seems that the only closer alternative is to use Emacs itself (as an IDE) instead of Eclipse.

Comment: You might be also interested in Emacs Eclim - http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsEclim

Comment: Thanks maarons. I didn't realize how large the Emacs community is out there. This is very impressive.

Comment: BTW, what does the Emacs+ plugin (suggested by Jesper) offer beyond the Emacs key binding already built into Eclipse?

Comment: How to enable Emacs key bindings in Eclipse 3.5.2: Windows > Preferences > General > Keys > Scheme: Emacs (change from Default) -- unfortunately, this seems more like a joke rather than Emacs binding as "Undo", for example, maps into Ctrl-Z instead of Ctrl-x+U. Useless.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse 3.5.1 and undo is mapped to C-_ as it should, unfortunately some stuff doesn't work (M-^ or C-m are annoying) but most of the time it's close enough...

Comment: Well, I tried the Emacs+ plugin and while it's closer than the built-in bindings, it's still not close enough for me. So, I switched back to the tried & true GNU Emacs and here is an excellent relevant post: http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/2191-could-not-find-main-class-program-will-exit.html#post4322